# How to speed up this Rets feed import from MLS using Phrets (Bright MLS)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, phrets

I am new to RETS importing so I developed this script:

```php
<?php
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

/* --------------------------------------------------------
------- GET THE ARRAY OF SELECTED FIELDS TO INDEX FROM MLS ---
--------------------------------------------------------*/

require_once ('retsfields.php');
$filteredretsfields = array_filter( $retsfields );

/* --------------------------------------------------------
------- DATABASE ------------
--------------------------------------------------------*/

$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION sql_mode = ''");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$startTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* ------------ IS A PREVIOUS FEED ALREADY RUNNING? ----------------*/
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$getFeedRunning = "SELECT * FROM feedsettings WHERE name = 'feedrunning';";
$rowFeedRunning = $conn->query( $getFeedRunning );

while($FeedRunning = $rowFeedRunning->fetch_assoc()) {
    $feedRunningValue = $FeedRunning['val'];
}

if ($feedRunningValue == '0') {

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- UPDATE FEEDRUNNING -------------------------*/
    /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $updateFeedRunning = "UPDATE feedsettings SET val='1', updated_at='".$startTime."' WHERE name='feedrunning';";

    if ($conn->query($updateFeedRunning) === TRUE) {
        //echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        //echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- ADD TO LOG TABLE -------------------------- */
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $sqlLogs = "INSERT INTO importlogs (totallistings, starttime, endtime, totalimages, lastindex, newlastindex, comments) VALUES ('', '$startTime', '', '', '', '', 'Feed started!')";

    if ( $conn->query( $sqlLogs ) === true ) {
        //echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    /* --------------------------------------------------------
    ------- RETS APIS ------------
    --------------------------------------------------------*/

    require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

    $config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
    $config->setLoginUrl('xxx')
           ->setUsername('xxx')
           ->setPassword('xxx')
           ->setUserAgent('Bright RETS Application/1.0')
            ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');

    $rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);

    $connect = $rets->Login();

    /* -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- AMAZON S3 ---------------------------*/
    /* -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('xxx', 'xxx');

    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'region'  => 'us-east-2',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => $credentials,
        //'debug' => true
    ]);

    $s3->registerStreamWrapper();

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  LASTINDEX: WHAT WAS THE LAST IMPORTED DATE: EG: 2019-06-24T08:45:45 */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $getLastIndex = "SELECT * FROM feedsettings WHERE name = 'lastindex';";
    $rowLastIndex = $conn->query( $getLastIndex );

    while($lastIndex = $rowLastIndex->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lastIndexValue = $lastIndex['val'];
    }

    $newLastIndex = date('Y-m-d').'T'.date('H:i:s');

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* --- FETCH NUMBER OF LISTINGS: MAP LASTINDEX TO MODIFICATION DATE ----*/
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $totalProperties = $rets->Search('Property', 'ALL', '(ModificationTimestamp='.$lastIndexValue.'+)', ['Limit' => 1]);

    $totalPropertiesCount = $totalProperties->getTotalResultsCount();
    $numberOfOffsetPages = ceil($totalPropertiesCount / 1000);

    $iCount = 0;
    $numberOfPhotos = 0;

    for ($offset = 1; $offset <= $totalPropertiesCount; $offset=($iCount*1000)+1) {

        /* ------------ FETCH RECORDS PER 1000 LISTINGS --------------- */
        $results = $rets->Search('Property', 'ALL', '(ModificationTimestamp='.$lastIndexValue.'+)', [
            'Limit' => 1000,
            'Offset' => $offset,
            'StandardNames' => 0, // give system names
        ]);

        foreach ( $results as $r ) {

            $retsdata = array();

            foreach ( $filteredretsfields as $key => $value ) {
                $retsdata[ $key ] = htmlspecialchars( $r[ $value ], ENT_QUOTES );
            }

            $date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

            $retsdata['created_at'] = $date;
            $retsdata['updated_at'] = $date;

            $columns = implode( ",", array_keys( $retsdata ) );
            $values  = "'" . implode( "','", $retsdata ) . "'";

            $searchsql = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE ListingId = '" . $r['ListingId'] . "'";
            $checkExistingListings = $conn->query( $searchsql );

            if ( $checkExistingListings->num_rows > 0 ) {
                //DELETE EXISTING RECORDS
                $conn->query( 'DELETE FROM properties WHERE ListingId = "' . $r['ListingId'] . '";' );
                $conn->query( 'DELETE FROM images WHERE ListingId = "' . $r['ListingId'] . '";' );
                //TODO DELETE THE EXISTING IMAGES
                //INSERT NEW RECORD
                $sql = "INSERT INTO properties ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
            } else {
                //INSERT NEW RECORD
                $sql = "INSERT INTO properties ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
            }

            if ( $conn->query( $sql ) === true ) {
                //echo "New record created successfully -> ";
                //echo $sql;
            } else {
                //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /* ------------ FETCH IMAGES ----------------*/
            /* -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            $numberOfPhotos = $numberOfPhotos + $r['TotalPhotos'];

            $photos = '';
            $photoNumber = 0;

            if ($r['TotalPhotos'] != 0) {
                for ($photoNumber = 1; $photoNumber <= $r['TotalPhotos']; $photoNumber++) {

                    /* ----- FETCH PHOTO PER PHOTO TO AVOID MEMORY ISSUES ----- */
                    /* ---- FETCH ALL PHOTOS IN ONE GETOBJECT() CRASHED THE SERVER ---- */
                    $photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Thumbnail", $r['ListingKey'], $photoNumber);

                    for ($i = 0; $i < 4096; $i++) {
                        preg_replace('/\d/', '', 1);
                    }

                    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
                        $listing = $r['ListingId'];
                        $number = $photo->getObjectId();

                        if (!$photo->isError()) {
                            $key = $listing.'/image-'.$listing.'-'.$number.'.jpg';
                            // Send a PutObject request and get the result object.

                            $context = stream_context_create(array(
                                's3' => array(
                                    'ACL' => 'public-read'
                                )
                            ));

                            /* -- COPY THE PHOTO TO S3 -- */
                            file_put_contents('s3://my-bucket-url/'.$key, $photo->getContent(), 0, $context);

                            $sqlImages = "INSERT INTO images (ListingId, storedUrl) VALUES ('$listing', '$key')";

                            if ( $conn->query( $sqlImages ) === true ) {
                                //echo "New record created successfully -> ";
                                //echo $sql;
                            } else {
                                //echo "Error: " . $sqlImages . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            //echo 'error';
                        }
                    }
                }

                unset($photos);
            }

            /* ----- CLEAN VARIABLES --------------------------------*/
            unset($columns, $values, $retsdata);
        }

        /* ----- CLEAN VARIABLES --------------------------------*/
        unset($results);
        $iCount++;
    }

    $endTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- UPDATE LASTINDEX -------------------------*/
    /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $updateLastIndex = "UPDATE feedsettings SET val='".$newLastIndex."', updated_at='".$endTime."' WHERE name='lastindex';";

    if ($conn->query($updateLastIndex) === TRUE) {
        //echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        //echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- UPDATE FEEDRUNNING -------------------------*/
    /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $updateFeedRunning = "UPDATE feedsettings SET val='0', updated_at='".$endTime."' WHERE name='feedrunning';";

    if ($conn->query($updateFeedRunning) === TRUE) {
        //echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        //echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- ADD TO LOG TABLE -------------------------- */
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $sqlLogs = "INSERT INTO importlogs (totallistings, starttime, endtime, totalimages, lastindex, newlastindex) VALUES ($totalPropertiesCount, '$startTime', '$endTime', $numberOfPhotos, '$lastIndexValue', '$newLastIndex')";

    if ( $conn->query( $sqlLogs ) === true ) {
        //echo "New record created successfully -> ";
        //echo $sql;
    } else {
        //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

} else {

    $endTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* ---------------- ADD TO LOG TABLE -------------------------- */
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $sqlLogs = "INSERT INTO importlogs (totallistings, starttime, endtime, totalimages, lastindex, newlastindex, comments) VALUES ('', '$startTime', '$endTime', '', '', '', 'Feed already running!')";

    if ( $conn->query( $sqlLogs ) === true ) {
        //echo "New record created successfully -> ";
        //echo $sql;
    } else {
        //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

$conn->close();
```

In principle the code is running fine, although I had some memory issues, see my comments in the code. My main concern is on how to improve, speed up the import process. The MLS I need to index is Bright MLS. Bright requires that we store all data, including images on our servers. So I had this code running for the last 18 hours and it imported around 8000 listing and 200.000 pictures, then it crashed due to a bad gateway.

I know this massive import is only needed once (in the beginning), after I can do partial updates every x hours.

**So I have 2 questions:**

- How can I make it more stable to allow me recover form these crashes more easily, because it would mean I need to restart every time from the beginning.
- How can I speed the import up, because at this speed, It would take 11 days straight to import all the listings. Maybe I don't need to keep a 5 year history

I was thinking of importing all content without images, store the images urls, so the full MLS is indexed. After I would run a process to fetch these images one by one (and that would take 11 days). Any ideas on pushing image import into an Amazon SQS queue (no experience).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split listings data and images import processes. Download all the listings details at first, then try to get their images. This way, there will be no crash or memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Am just answering your two questions

- How can I make it more stable to allow me recover form these crashes more easily, because it would mean I need to restart every time from the beginning.

You can split your query to fetch data. Consider you need last 5 year history data, then you can split the query like following

```
$query1 = (ModificationTimestamp=2016-01-01T00:00:00-2016-12-31T23:59:59);
$query2 = (ModificationTimestamp=2017-01-01T00:00:00-2017-12-31T23:59:59);
$query3 = (ModificationTimestamp=2018-01-01T00:00:00-2018-12-31T23:59:59);
$query4 = (ModificationTimestamp=2019-01-01T00:00:00-2019-12-31T23:59:59);
$query5 = (ModificationTimestamp=2020-01-01T00:00:00+);
```

If required, split further and run. May be run these split up queries in loop, as per your logic. Thus if stopped in-between, you know which batch it got crashed and from where you need to restart.

- How can I speed the import up, because at this speed, It would take 11 days straight to import all the listings. Maybe I don't need to keep a 5 year history

This one totally depends on MLS board. They hold the extraction speed. Some MLS boards may increase the bandwidth temporarily on request. Within that time try to extract full data.